# Interaction between entities

Tags: qt, design-patterns

Consider I have some environment(let's name it `world`) and some entities(let's name them `bot`s), that belong to the world. I want bots to interact with each other(e.g. get a list of the bots located in the field of view of the bot). But if bots don't know about their environment, they also don't know about the others. So the question is - how does this interaction implemented in real world applications?

The solution I see is to give bots the pointer to the world, but I find it quite illogical, because each bot will have the same «rights» while interacting with other bots as the world has.

The solution I use at this moment is QT signals & slots conception. Each bot has a signal `queryNeighbours(Bot *requester, QVector<Bot *> *result)`, and the world has a slot `giveNeighbours(Bot *requester, QVector<Bot *> *result)`. So, then I connect bots' signals with the world's slot, and when a bot needs to get the neighbours, it just gets them like:

```
QVector<Bot *> bots;
emit queryBots(this, &bots);
```

However, I think there is some pattern, implementing what I need, so I wouldn't need QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a class whose only aim is to handle the relations between bots and make that class available to both the world and the bots :)

Comment: I thought about this, but hoped I might find something easier. However, thanks for the suggestion(it's actually named `Mediator pattern`).

Comment: It was just an idea. So it's great, we've both learnt something :)

Comment: If it was me, I would use the Mediator pattern as you two have mentioned.  However, if the bots only need to interact with each other, the class that is handling the relationship doesn't need to be available to the world environments as well (unlike in ixM's answer).  All the bots can just inherit from a base class that contains the mediator (and have it protected).